# How to create a dynamic route for multiple categories of ecommerce in laravel?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, e-commerce, dynamic-variables

I want to:

1. Create a dynamic route logic to handle category and subcategory in URL.
2. Send a dynamic variable to where clause in Products Model

Web.php Route file:

```
Route::prefix("products")->group(function () {
    Route::get('{category_one}/{category_two}',[ProductsController::class,'index'])->where(['category_one'=> '[A-Za-z]+','category_two'=>'[A-Za-z]+']);
});
```

ProductsController.php

```
use App\Models\Products;
public function index()
    {
        $products = new Products;
        $products=$products->getProducts();
        return view('pages.products')->with(['products'=>$products]);
    }
```

Products.php Model

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
public function getProducts(){
        $products = DB::table('products')->where([['category_one', "{category_one}"],['category_two', "{category_two}"]])->latest()->get();
        return $products;
    }
```

I'm having a problem to fetch {category_one} and {category_two} dynamically from the URL.

ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_two'
> in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where (`category_one`
> = {category_one} and `category_two` = {category_two}) order by `created_at` desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the route parameters from the request object

```
use App\Models\Products;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $categoryOne = $request->route('category_one');
    $categoryTwo = $request->route('category_two');

    $products = Products::where([
        ['category_one', $categoryOne], 
        ['category_two', $categoryTwo]
    ])->latest()->get();

    
    return view('pages.products',['products'=>$products]);
}
```